# How to add or update a column value using joins in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Need to find how can we update a column in a dataframe say `df` based on equality condition on another dataframe  say `ds`.
In order to reproduce this issue, you can just copy paste the same to your notebook.

Example:
df is created as

```
data = [["101", "sravan", "vignan"],
        ["102", "ramya", "vvit"],
        ["103", "rohith", "klu"],
        ["104", "sridevi", "vignan"],
        ["105", "gnanesh", "iit"]]
columns = ['rollNo', 'name', 'lastName']
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data, schema=columns, verifySchema=True)
```

another data frame is `ds`:

```
ds = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        ("100", "2015-01-01", "2015-01-01T13:51:39.340396Z"),
        ("101", "2015-01-01", "2015-01-01T12:14:58.597216Z"),
        ("102", "2015-01-01", "2015-01-01T13:51:40.417052Z"),
        ("103", "2015-01-01", "2015-01-01T13:51:40.519832Z"),
        ("107", "2015-01-01", "2015-01-01T13:51:40.519832Z"),
        ("108", "2015-01-01", "2015-01-01T13:51:40.519832Z"),
        ("109", "2015-01-01", "2015-01-01T13:51:40.519832Z"),
    ],
    ["rollNo", "creation_date", "last_update_time"]
)
```

Now we perform join(leftanti) join to create `dt` to find non-common items on the left table:

```
dt = df.join(ds, ["rollNo"], "leftanti")
dt.show(5,False)
df.show(5,False)

response of leftanti join dt dataframe is like below

+------+-------+--------+
|rollNo|name   |lastName|
+------+-------+--------+
|104   |sridevi|vignan  |
|105   |gnanesh|iit     |
+------+-------+--------+



original df dataframe is

+------+-------+--------+
|rollNo|name   |lastName|
+------+-------+--------+
|101   |sravan |vignan  |
|102   |ramya  |vvit    |
|103   |rohith |klu     |
|104   |sridevi|vignan  |
|105   |gnanesh|iit     |
+------+-------+--------+
```

Issue is when trying to add another column to `df` based on an equality condition on both dataframes as mentioned below, it isn't giving expected response, which is to update only those rows which has same `rollNo` to `true` and rest to `false`:

```
df.withColumn('is_deleted', when(dt.rollNo == df.rollNo, True).otherwise(False)).show(5,False) 

Response received:
+------+-------+--------+----------+
|rollNo|name   |lastName|is_deleted|
+------+-------+--------+----------+
|101   |sravan |vignan  |true      |
|102   |ramya  |vvit    |true      |
|103   |rohith |klu     |true      |
|104   |sridevi|vignan  |true      |
|105   |gnanesh|iit     |true      |
+------+-------+--------+----------+

Response expected:
+------+-------+--------+----------+
|rollNo|name   |lastName|is_deleted|
+------+-------+--------+----------+
|101   |sravan |vignan  |false     |
|102   |ramya  |vvit    |false     |
|103   |rohith |klu     |false     |
|104   |sridevi|vignan  |true      | # this shud be updated to true
|105   |gnanesh|iit     |true      | # this shud be updated to true
+------+-------+--------+----------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Use left_outer instead. Code below

```
 dt = df.join(ds.select('rollNo',col('creation_date').alias('is_deleted')), ["rollNo"], "left_outer").withColumn('is_deleted',when(col('is_deleted').isNull(),True).otherwise(False))
    dt.show(truncate=False)

+------+-------+--------+----------+
|rollNo|name   |lastName|is_deleted|
+------+-------+--------+----------+
|101   |sravan |vignan  |false     |
|102   |ramya  |vvit    |false     |
|103   |rohith |klu     |false     |
|104   |sridevi|vignan  |true      |
|105   |gnanesh|iit     |true      |
+------+-------+--------+----------+
```

Answer (score 1):

We can create a temp list and then use `isin` method to filter out rows. Something like below:

```
rolls = []           
dt = df.join(ds, ["rollNo"], "leftanti")
dataCollect = dt.collect()
for row in dataCollect:
    print(row['rollNo']) 
    rolls.append(row['rollNo'])
print(rolls)
dt.show(5,False)
df.show(5,False)
df.withColumn('is_deleted', when(df.rollNo.isin(rolls), True).otherwise(False)).show(5,False)
```